# Supporting two components with the same file

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.11

I'm working on an installer which has two features. Either/both features require installing the same exe in the same location, however for one feature it would be installed as a service, the other feature would be installed as just an executable. I have been trying to create two components (within the same directory - which is probably the problem...):

```
        <Component Id="cmpB8A68336ACB13FCB99813AFBF8C7768A_Service" Guid="decd2298-65a1-4e99-9a04-6a285fdb8900">
          <File Id="filC0A81797D07EB7C3ACE940F99AA9FEDC_1" Source="$PathTo\SomeExe.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
          <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceId" DisplayName="ServiceDisplayName" Name="ServiceName" Description="Service Desc" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal" Vital="yes" Interactive="no" />
          <ServiceControl Id="ServiceId" Name="ServiceName" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
          <ServiceConfig ServiceName="ServiceName" OnInstall="yes" DelayedAutoStart="yes" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmpB8A68336ACB13FCB99813AFBF8C7768A" Guid="5c226bcd-aa63-46f5-bc16-b3e7c3d50cb2">
          <File Id="filC0A81797D07EB7C3ACE940F99AA9FEDC_2" Source="PathTo\SomeExe.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
```

And then I have two ComponentGroups

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ExeWithoutService">
...
      <ComponentRef Id="cmpB8A68336ACB13FCB99813AFBF8C7768A" />
...
</ComponentGroup>
```

and

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ExeWithService">
...
      <ComponentRef Id="cmpB8A68336ACB13FCB99813AFBF8C7768A_Service" />
...
</ComponentGroup>
```

But because two components have the same file in the same directory I get an error message, something along the lines of:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ICE30: The target file 'qlmjmveu.exe|SomeExe.exe' is installed in '[ProgramFilesFolder]\InstallLoc\' by two different components on an LFN system: 'cmpB8A68336ACB13FCB99813AFBF8C7768A_Service' and 'cmpB8A68336ACB13FCB99813AFBF8C7768A'. This breaks component reference counting.
```

In my Product I have

```
      <Feature Id="MainProgram" Title="The Service Application" Description="The service application" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExeWithService" />
      </Feature>
      <Feature Id="ServiceApp" Title="App" Description="The stand alone application" Level="10">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExeWithoutService" />
      </Feature>
```

I don't necessarily like the idea of two components, but I want to install the service if MainApp is installed (or both MainApp and ServiceApp), and without service if only ServiceApp is installed. Any thoughts about how to go about this?